# Why am I getting a file_put_contents error even after clearing the cache and modifying storage, vendor and bootstrap permissions CentOS?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I have read many similar posts with a similar error, but after doing the recommended solutions for each of them, I still have not had any success sending a POST API request to my Laravel API instance hosted locally on my vagrant CentOS server.

The error message:

```
ErrorException: file_put_contents(/vagrant/html/test/storage/framework/cache/data/a2/76/a2767fcc897a34fbe4b83d0a6ad5f44445bd07a5):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file 
/vagrant/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 135
```

What I have tried:
Running the following commands both on the local Laravel instance and on Vagrant:

```
chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/ vendor/
```

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

```
sudo chown -R root: storage/ vendor/
```

Thanks in advance for any help! Cheers!

Comment: So the directory path up to and including `/vagrant/html/test/storage/framework/cache/data/a2/76/` exists? (`file_put_contents` will _not_ create missing directories along the path for you.)

Comment: @CBroe Laravel creates any folder below `storage/framework/cache` as part of it's caching system. The issue is probably from permissions instead of file_put_contents. That said, making root own any folders in the Laravel structure is a bad idea.

Comment: @CBroe thanks so much for the quick response! Yes, I verified that the directory exists, and then I ran
`chmod -R 775 ./*`
there. Also thank you @aynber but maybe chown would resolve it though bad practice? (It didn't seem to work anyway though... hmm)